# Solaar loses permissions after reboot - need to unplug Unifying receiver each time

Tags: logitech-unifying

I just installed Solaar to use with my Logitech K520.
I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Solar 0.9.2
Each time I reboot, I must unplug and replug the receiver, and then turn off and on the keyboard. After that, everything works great. The error message is the same one given right after installation:

> Found a Logitech Receiver (/dev/hidraw1), but did not have permission to open it.
>   If you've just installed Solaar, try removing the receiver and plugging it back in.

I get the same error after quitting and restarting the program, although this doesn't seem to interrupt the function of the keyboard. (No need to unplug, etc.)

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue with SteamOS, after installing solaar 0.9.2 from the Debian repos. It didn't seem to have properly installed the udev rules. I haven't restarted to double-check (and if it changes anything I will edit this answer), but I believe the solution is as follows:

1. Make sure all [required libraries](http://pwr.github.io/Solaar/installation.html) are installed.
2. As root, create the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/42-logitech-unifying-receiver.rules` and open it in your favorite text editor.
3. Paste in the contents of the udev rules from the [github repository](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pwr/Solaar/master/rules.d/42-logitech-unify-permissions.rules) and save the file.
4. Physically remove the receiver and re-insert it.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Not to jump on the "me too" bandwagon, but this worked for me as well, with a Logitech G502 Lightspeed mouse, on Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks!

Comment: Same for me. Logitech anywhere 2s+mx keys keyboard +1.

Comment: See also my full installation and setup instructions here: [How do I install and configure the latest version of `solaar` to manage my Logitech wireless mouse or keyboard on Linux Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1390784/327339). I explain the udev rules setup as well as how to upgrade to the latest version of `solaar` in order to get the extra features it contains, which are many.

Comment: This worked on ubuntu (mint) for a k400 logitech keyboard. Thank you